# django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: django, git, postgresql, operationalerror

I have cloned a repo from github and working on it. The project was in django and using postgres as database. This project is now on the production side and I need to make some changes to it. The database specs is :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'NAME': 'project_name',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or           '127.0.0.1'
        # for localhost through TCP.
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I want to run this on my local host but I am not able to. I am getting error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have searched for this problem but couldn't find a solution that could help me. Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Have you created the database with the project_name and 'admin' user. And are you sure the password is not required?

Comment: yeah I tried creating the database in PgAdminIII but it gives the same error there too.

Comment: there seems to be some problem with your database. why dont you try the following commands in your terminal `psql -U postgres` followed by `create database project_name;`. if this works out change the user in the settings to postgres

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score 33):

If you want to use a local password less connection then you need to remove the values "HOST", "PORT" and "PASSWORD".

With this configuration your connector will try to connect using a unix domain socket which is the only allowed password less connection allowed by default in Postgres

Comment: Try to change the loggin to postgres instead of admin

Comment: where should I do that??

Comment: In your settings.py, try 'user': 'postgres'

Comment: this was close for me, after reviewing `settings.py` (`'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),`) I realized I had not activated the env vars in this new shell.

Answer (score 10):

I can think of two possible solutions to this problem.

**First**, if there is no password for the database, remove the `PASSWORD` key. E.g.:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'project_name',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Second**, if there is a password for the database, provide it in the `PASSWORD` key:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'project_name',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': '<YOUR PASSWORD HERE...>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid thing. But for me the problem was that postgres wasn't actually running. So always check whether it's running.

In Linux:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO CREATE NEW DATABASE**
Open pgAdmin, left click on Servers then right click on PostgreSQL--->Create--->Database. Fill the database name field, let say **SCHOOL** and save.

**TO REGISTER SERVER**
Right click on Servers then Register-->Server, fill the Name field with any name of your choice for example admin. Navigate to connection, fill the Hostname/address field with **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**,fill the password field let say **1234** and save password, leave other fields as they are.
[image may not be available at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZH6.png)

Finally your codes snippet will be like the below one;

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'SCHOOL',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '1234',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me now,
I found out it was db version.

Answer (score 0):

I have got an easy solution for the error "jango.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"....

first open your cmd and start your postgress server stepwise:
step 1: first fine this path "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin>" here 16 is my postgres version, you must change it according to your version.
step 2: run this command "psql -U postgres". your cmd will look like this "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\bin>psql -U postgres".
step 3: enter your password
step 4: \c your_database_name
then you'll see a msg "You are now connected to database "your_database_name" as user "postgres"."

now go to your code editor and open your code editors terminal in the right directory and copy and paste this "pip install python-dotenv
"
now add these line of code in your settings.py

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

now run your project.
It will surely work now.